# Copy data from multiple worksheets into one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to copy data from multiple worksheets (in cells M78:078, 3 columns M, N, and O) into one, where the name in the column L of the summary sheet matches the worksheet name (pasting into columns Z:AA in the summary sheet).

The code is erroring out:

```vb
Sub Output_data()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ActiveSheet.Range("L:L").Value = wkSht.Name Then
        ws.Range("M78:O78").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("L").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=wkSht.Range("Z:AA").Paste
    End If
Next ws           
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error and on which line?

Comment: Do you only want to copy data from columns M and O? Because if you're doing M:O that's actually columns M, N, and O.  Your destination is only two columns, Z and AA, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, all three columns

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.  I commented the code in an attempt to explain what it does.

```
Sub Output_data()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsGet As Worksheet
    Dim LCell As Range
    Dim sDataCol As String
    Dim lHeaderRow As Long

    sDataCol = "L"  'Change to be the column you want to match sheet names agains
    lHeaderRow = 1  'Change to be what your actual header row is

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Summary")    'Change this to be your Summary sheet

    'Check for values in sDataCol
    With ws.Range(sDataCol & lHeaderRow + 1, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sDataCol).End(xlUp))
        If .Row <= lHeaderRow Then Exit Sub 'No data

        'Loop through sDataCol values
        For Each LCell In .Cells
            'Check if sheet named that value exists
            If Evaluate("ISREF('" & LCell.Text & "'!A1)") Then
                'Found a matching sheet, copy M78:O78 to the corresponding row, column Z and on
                Set wsGet = wb.Sheets(LCell.Text)
                wsGet.Range("M78:O78").Copy ws.Cells(LCell.Row, "Z")
            End If
        Next LCell
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that, could you confirm what the A1 relates to?

Comment: -- It's just erroring out - Run-time error '13' type mismatch on that line

Comment: @DRod The A1 is just there so that Evaluate can use the `ISREF` function and test if a worksheet exists.  In this case, it is testing if the worksheet name in `LCell.Text` exists.  The Evaluate line shouldn't give an error at all.  If the sheet exists, it should return `TRUE` and if the sheet doesn't exist it should return `FALSE`.  I have tested the code and it works as expected for me.  Did you modify the code?

Comment: The changes have been to update the header row, and change the sheet name from "Summary" to "Sheet1"